# Building a heatmap in R with more information

Tags: r, heatmap

I made a heatmap on R and most of it is one colour.  I have two columns of data which showed up as various colours, but the rest of it is red.

Does anyone know how to increase the "resolution" of this?  I don't mean anything about how to make the image more clear (which is why I think I'm having trouble searching for info on it).  I mean, how do I make my heatmap more meaningful and not all mostly one colour.

Thanks and sorry if this has been answered somewhere else.  I think I don't know the key term I need to search properly.

Edit:

Here is the code I used so far (heatdata is my matrix):

```
heatmap <- heatmap(heatdata,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=cm.colors(256),scale="row")
```

Comment: What code have you written to produce the heatmap?

Comment: I should have mentioned it, I've added it above now @tospig